# Systemd NetworkNamespacePath not working

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I'm trying to launch an app inside a network namespace from a systemd service. I tried using `NetworkNamespacePath=` but when I use it all network requests fail. If I launch the app in `ExecStart` using `ip netns exec` it works, but it's not very clean and I have to reset the user using `sudo`. What am I doing wrong with `NetworkNamespacePath=`?

I don't think it should matter much but I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. This is my service file.

```ini
[Unit]
Description=My Service
# netns.service sets up the network namespace
After=network-online.target netns.service
Requires=network-online.target netns.service

[Service]
Type=simple
# The following doesn't work, app starts but every network request fails
NetworkNamespacePath=/run/netns/mynetns
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/app
# If I change it to this, it works
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ip netns exec mynetns sudo -u user /usr/bin/app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

It is likely related to DNS, or at least was for me in the same scenario. The default system resolver may not be accessible from the network namespace.

As noted in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html), `ip netns exec` automatically creates namespace-specific configuration bind mounts which will not be reproduced by your systemd unit:

> For applications that are aware of network namespaces, the convention is to look for global network configuration files first in `/etc/netns/NAME/` then in `/etc/`. For example, if you want a different version of `/etc/resolv.conf` for a network namespace used to isolate your vpn you would name it `/etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf`.
>
> `ip netns exec` automates handling of this configuration, file convention for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace configure files into their traditional location in `/etc`.

Therefore, if you have set a custom resolver in `/etc/netns/mynetns/resolv.conf`, you must bind it in the service file:

```
[Service]
NetworkNamespacePath=/run/netns/mynetns
BindReadOnlyPaths=/etc/netns/mynetns/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
```